# JavaScript - I want to hide certain buttons on the webpage I've created

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

I have made an e-commerce website. So, when an order is placed, the user has to wait until the confirmation of the order. So, there are two buttons which are of no use until the order has not been confirmed

The JavaScript code is as follows:

```js
var docketDownlondLink = "--"; var rescheduled_pickupLink = "--";
                       if(ordertype == 'courier'){
                           $('#btnDownloadDockets').css('display','none');
                           $('#btnDownloadDockets').attr('data-orderid',order_id);
                           docketDownlondLink = '<a style="font-size: 14px;" href="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.geniebazaar.in/order/courierlabels/'+tracking_no+'.zip" class="" title="Download Docket"> <i class="fas fa-download"></i></a>';
                           rescheduled_pickupLink = '<a style="font-size: 14px;" href="/reschedulePickup/'+encoded_cart_id+'" class="" title="Reschedule Pickup"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> </a>';
                        }else{
                            $('#btnDownloadDockets').css('display','none');
                            $('#btnDownloadDockets').attr('data-orderid',"");
                        }

                       orderStatus = status;

                       if(address.trim() == ""){
                            if(typeof street != "undefined"){
                                address += street;
                            }

                            if(typeof landmark != "undefined"){
                                address += landmark;
                            }         

                            if(typeof postal_code != "undefined"){
                                address += " - "+postal_code;
                            }
                       }

                       if(typeof courier_code == 'undefined'){
                           courier_code = "";
                       }
                       
                       if(description.trim() != ""){
                           itemname += "<br/>"+description;
                       }

                       if(mode_of_transport.trim() != ""){
                           itemname += "<br/> Mode: "+mode_of_transport;
                       }

                       if(courier_code != ""){
                           itemname += "<br/> Courier: "+courier_code.toUpperCase();
                       }
                       
                       if(tracking_no.trim() != ""){
                           itemname += "<br/>Docket : "+tracking_no;
                       }

                       if(pickup_num.trim() != ""){
                           itemname += "<br/>Pickup :"+pickup_num;
                       }

                       if(remark != ""){
                           itemname += "<br/>Remark :"+remark;
                       }
                       
                       if(typeof courierStatus != 'undefined'){
                           if(courierStatus == ""){
                               courierStatus = status;
                           }
                       }
                       
                       var isFreeItem = 0;
                       if(amt <=0 && typeof couponCode != 'undefined'){
                           isFreeItem = 1;
                       }
                       
                       var markup = "<tr>";
                           
                    
                        markup += "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='record' class='cart_id_input' id='cart_id_input_"+cartid+"' data-cart_item='"+itemname.replace(regexRemoveSpecialCharacters, '')+"' data-cart_id="+cartid+" value="+cartid+"> </td>"+
                                    "<td> <span style='text-decoration:"+textDecoration+"'>" + (itemname).replace(regexRemoveSpecialCharacters, '') + '</span> <br/> '+substitute_product_name.replace(regexRemoveSpecialCharacters, '')+' <input type="hidden" name="product[]" value='+escape(itemname)+' />  <input type="hidden" name="serviceid[]" value='+serviceid+' >  ';
                       
                       if(cartorderType == 'courier'){
                           markup += "<a href='javascript:void(0);' data-cartid="+cartid+" class='viewCourierDetails'>View More</a>";
                       }
                       markup += "</td>";
                            
                        markup += "<td>"+hsnCode+"</td>"            

                       if(isFreeItem == 1){
                           markup +="<td class='text-center'>" + quantity + ' <input type="hidden" name="qty[]" value='+escape(quantity)+' /> </td>';
                           markup +="<td class='text-center'> "+shippedQty+" <input type='hidden' name='shipped_qty[]' value="+shippedQty+" /> </td>"+
                                 "<td> Free <input type='hidden' name='price[]' value="+amt+" /> </td>"+
                                 "<td> Free <input type='hidden' name='gst[]' value="+cart_amount+" /> </td>";
                       }else{
                            if((status =="approval_pending" || orderType != 'genie') && shippedQty <= 0 ){
                                 markup +="<td class='text-center'><input type='number' name='qty[]' style='width:30%;' class='cart_quantity_input' data-cart_id="+cartid+" value="+escape(quantity)+" /> </td>";
                            }else{       
                                markup +="<td class='text-center'>" + quantity + ' <input type="hidden" name="qty[]" value='+escape(quantity)+' /> </td>';
                            }
                            
                            markup +="<td class='text-center'> "+shippedQty+" <input type='hidden' name='shipped_qty[]' value="+shippedQty+" /> </td>"+
                                    "<td>" + amt + " <input type='hidden' name='price[]' value="+amt+" /> </td>"+
                                    "<td>" + cart_amount.toFixed(2) + " <input type='hidden' name='gst[]' value="+cart_amount+" /> </td>";
                        }

                        
                         if(ordertype == 'courier'){
                                markup +="<td>" + courierStatus + " <input type='hidden' name='gst[]' value="+status+" /> </td>";
                         }else{
                             markup +="<td>" + status + " <input type='hidden' name='gst[]' value="+status+" /> </td>";
                         }
                         
                         if(docketDownlondLink != "--"){
                            markup +="<td>" + docketDownlondLink+" | "+ rescheduled_pickupLink + "</td>";
                            $('#td-action').css('display','block');
                         }else{
                            $('#td-action').css('display','none');
                         }
                         
                         markup +="</tr>";
                        $('#itemlist tbody').append(markup);
                   }
               }
```

So what I want is to hide the buttons until the order has been confirmed and display it once it's confirmed. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Not enough information/code here to know how to proceed.

Comment: I've updated the code now, can you check? Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to achieve this, and depend on your need. I will share one of them with you.

First we need to define how do we know that an order is confirmed ¿We are pulling the information of the order from API or do we have access to that state change?

If the first answer is yes we can do something like this
You will need to set the base class of the element with a display none, then create a second class called `show` with `display: block` or any display you need in yout layout

```
const getState = () => {
  const confirmation = fetch(...)
  if (confirmation) {
    const el = document.getElementById('#id')
    el.classList.add('show')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a small script to call a button

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
background-color: blue;
   border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius:10px;
}
button {
  background-color: GREEN;
    border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>


</style>
</head>
<body>


<button onclick="myFunction()">CONFIRM</button>
<button type="submit" id="myDIV">SUBMIT</button>

<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```